# Валидация форм в yii

Tags: yii

Есть например форма регистрации, одно из полей хочу проверить например регуляркой или своей какой то функцией, можно ли это совместить со стандартной валидацией или только в самом контролере проверять а потом уже добавлять ошибку ? типа такого

```
        if ($model->model()->count("login = :login", array(':login' => $model->login))) {
            // Указанный логин уже занят. Создаем ошибку и передаем в форму
            $model->addError('login', 'Логин уже занят');
            $this->render('registration', array('model' => $model));
        } else {
            // Выводим страницу что "все окей"
            $form->save();
            $this->render('registration_ok', array('model' => $model));
        }

    } else {
        $this->render('registration', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

при таком раскладе кстати ошибка "Логин уже занят" появляется только при явном нажитии на кнопку в форме, а ajax валидация проходит на ура, как бы сделать так чтобы при заполнении формы сразу происходила проверка на занятость логина ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так вы сделайте проверку поля login на уникальность стандартными средстьвами YII - называется  unique)

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('login', 'unique', 'allowEmpty'=>false, 'attributeName'=>'login', 'className'=>'ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВЕТЕ ИМЯ КЛАССА МОДЕЛИ ОПИСЫВАЮЩИЙ ЮЗЕРА'),
        //далее ваши еще проверки
    );
}
```

подробности вот [тут](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/form.validation.reference)

Answer (score 0):

если я вас правильно понял то можно сделать так

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['login'], 'chech_login'],
        ];
    }

    public function chech_login($attribute, $params){
        // ...
    }
```